# Why do planets not stop revolving around the Sun?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, conservation-laws

Why do planets revolving around the Sun not stop revolving? Note I am not asking why planets do not collapse with Sun.

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: What keeps them moving

Comment: What would *stop* them moving?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you're asking. Are you asking how planets get the energy to keep revolving? If so, no energy is dissipated as they orbit so no energy input is needed. Or are you asking [why planetary orbits are stable?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160785/why-are-planets-in-unstable-equilibrium-in-a-stable-orbit), in which case the linked question gives the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do planets get energy to revolve around sun?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56278/)

Comment: It is not clear from link given by John Rennie

Comment: Why no energy is dissipated while planets orbit

Comment: Who says energy *isn't* being dissipated?

Comment: Sir john rennie said so in comments obove.

Comment: harshit, the answer can be summarized to something like: An object in nearly-uniform circular motion *stays* in nearly-uniform circular motion.

Comment: Is this what angular momentum explains?#HDE 226868

Answer (score 1):

The angular momentum of any particular planet around the Sun (or the angular momentum of the planet-Sun system around its center of mass) is huge.  To change the angular momentum of a system requires a torque exerted over some time interval:
$$\frac{dL}{dt}=\tau \hspace{1in} \Delta{L}=\int \tau dt $$

There are simply no torques large enough to change the angular momentum appreciably in time frames meeting human existence. Even planet-to-planet gravitational interactions don't create appreciable torques as far as revolution around the Sun is concerned.

The Sun (ideally as a spherical, radially distributed mass) exerts no torque on a planet about any point along their adjoining line.

On the other hand, the existence of Neptune was inferred by wobbles in the motion of Uranus due to their mutual gravitational interaction.

There are apparently some very small torques within the solar system which result in the precession of rotational axes, but nothing large enough to cause revolution to change.

Comment: I just told you. Nothing is changing their angular momentum. Do you understand what angular momentum is?

Comment: Do you mean that because of angular momentum planets will keep revolving around the sun.

Comment: Because nothing is **changing** the angular momentum of the planets.

Comment: Do Spinning top also have angular momentum?

Comment: See this link: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271/why-dont-spinning-tops-fall-over/1895#1895

Comment: @harshityagyasen Spinning tops have angular momentum, but they also have friction where the point contacts the ground.

Comment: The thing i am not understanding is how can angular momentum keep planets moving around the sun, it seems like a never ending process which will continue untill sun dies.