# Bertrand's Theorem: Perturbative Methods Leading to $1/r^3$ Solution

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, symmetry, orbital-motion, perturbation-theory

My professor and I have been working on a proof of [Bertrand's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) using perturbative methods. We have arrived at a solution yielding $1/r^3$, which we had presumed to be an incorrect result. While I'm new to his research, I have been obsessing over finding reconciliation or a [SPoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

However, after reading the last comment on the first reply to this particular SE post, I am reconsidering this result:  [An intuitive proof of Bertrand's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110123/). Can somebody elaborate on what @mmesser314 is talking about? I haven't seen a perturbation-based derivation lead to a $1/r^3$ result in the literature I've encountered. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying. If your result is that a potential $1/r^3$ yields closed orbit that is clearly wrong. Another way of looking at Bertrand's theorem is that for the two solutions (harmonic oscillator and $1/r$) there are additional conservation laws. For gravity this conservation is related to the Runge-Lenz vector.

Comment: Coming to @mmesser314 's comment you're talking about I think that's a typo, but he/she may be able to say more.

Answer (score 1):

I have been studying Bertrand's theorem recently. I won't comment on @mmesser314 answer but a classic reference for a proof using perturbation theory is [1]. A more recent paper working with $r(\theta)$ instead of trying to solve for $\theta(t)$, and also looking at oscillations about circular orbits is [2].

[1] Brown, Lowell S. (1978). “Forces giving no orbit precession”. In: American Journal of Physics 46.9, pp. 930– 931. doi: 10.1119/1.11519.

[2] Chin, Siu A. (2015). “A truly elementary proof of Bertrand’s theorem”. In: American Journal of Physics 83, p. 320.